# Bind subset of n rows from one dataframe to subset of different n rows of muliple other dataframes

Tags: r

I am attempting to bind a subset of rows from one dataframe to a subset of rows from 11 other dataframes repeatedly through a large dataset. E.g.

```
df=JAN        df=FEB

Day Jan       Day Feb

1    70       1   66
2    70       2   66
3    70       3   66
4    70       4   66
5    70       5   66
6    70       6   66
7    70       7   66
8    70       8   66
9    70       9   66
10   70       10  66
11   70       11  66
12   70       12  66
13   70       13  66
14   70       14  66
15   70       15  66
16   70       16  66
17   70       17  66
18   70       18  66
19   70       19  66
20   70       20  66
21   70       21  66
22   70       22  66
23   70       23  66
24   70       24  66
25   70       25  66
26   70       26  66
27   70       27  66
28   70       28  66
29   70
30   70
31   70
............................
```

In the example above, what I want to do is cbind rows 1:31 from df Jan with rows 1:28 from df Feb through to rows 1:31 from df Dec (not shown), then continue the cbind for the next 31 days in Jan (i.e. rows 32:62 from df Jan), then rows 29:56 from df Feb and so on.

There are 12 data frames in total (one for each month) that take the form as shown. There are 120 months of data in each data frame.

My output should be a single column and look like:

```
70 (repeated 31 times)
66 (repeated 28 times)
......................
```

I have trawled this site and others for help, but can't find anything directly applicable here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show a small example and expected output for easier understanding

Comment: Do you mean concatenate - c() - instead of cbind? row 1:2 from one column will only be two number.

Comment: Thanks @akrun - i have now done this.

Comment: Do you have a matrix or data.frame?

Comment: I do @akrun, but don't know how to get it up here

Comment: What do you mean by `how to get it up here`?

Comment: I mean I don't know how to make my data frame visible on this site. It is huge. The example above is a small excerpt from the real data frame.

Comment: The dataset you provided is fine for testing.  Just wanted to know whether you have a matrix or data.frame.  If I understand the question, you want to get data from every 2 rows and make it in a single column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create a grouping variable using `gl` for every 2 row, use that in the `tapply`, `unlist` the dataset to get the expected output.

```
unlist(tapply(as.matrix(df2), as.numeric(gl(nrow(df2), 2, nrow(df2)))[row(df2)], 
                            FUN=unlist), use.names=FALSE)
#[1] 70 70 64 64 58 58 66 66 61 61 59 59 53 53 56 56 69 69 77 77 74 74 72 72 71
#[26] 71 57 57 49 49 62 62 66 66 58 58 55 55 44 44 73 73 87 87 69 69 64 64
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset

```
 lst <- mget(toupper(month.abb[1:2]))
 #Here I am using only JAN and FEB, so `[1:2]`
 #For the OP's dataset, we need
 # lst <- mget(toupper(month.abb))
 library(data.table)
 DT <-  rbindlist(lapply(lst, function(x) 
     transform(x, GROUP= cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(Day)<0)))), idcol=TRUE)
 unlist(split(DT$Jan, DT$GROUP), use.names=FALSE)
# [1] 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70
# [26] 70 70 70 70 70 70 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66
# [51] 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
# [76] 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65
#[101] 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65 65
```

#### data

```
JAN <- data.frame(Day= rep(1:31, 2), Jan =rep(c(70, 42), each=31))
FEB <- data.frame(Day= rep(1:28, 2), Feb =rep(c(66, 65), each=28))
```

Comment: This is a great solution @akrun. Thanks for providing. Just one further issue: in my real dataset I'm not taking the first 2 rows of each column, I'm actually taking the number of days in each month. That means taking the first 31 rows for Jan, then the first 28 for Feb etc. through to the first 31 for  December, then the next 31 for Jan etc... Can the above be modified to do that?

Comment: @DJ-AFC  Could you show at least 2 months of data and expected output to understand how the data is arranged?

Comment: Thanks @akrun. I have now edited the question with a more suitable example on what I am looking for.

Comment: @DJ-AFC  If the file objects are named 'JAN', 'FEB', etc., `unlist(lapply(mget(toupper(month.abb)), '[', 2))`

Comment: Correct @akrun. There are 12 datasets - one for each month. Each dataset has a repeated value for the total number of days in that month (e.g. 31 for Jan, 28 for Feb etc. [no leap years incidentally]) as shown in my example. There are 120 months worth of repeated values in each dataset, e.g. Jan starts with 70 repeated 31 times, then another 119 values repeated 31 times. Same for other months, with exception that the repetition is by the number of days in that month.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @akrun but got the error message:                  Error in mget(toupper(JAN)) : variable names are limited to 10000 bytes

Comment: @DJ-AFC  I thought your object name is `"JAN"`

Comment: There are 12 separate dataframes named JAN, FEB, MAR etc.

Comment: @DJ_AFC In that case `lst <- mget(toupper(month.abb))` should get all the datasets in a `list`

Comment: This doesn't do what I need though @akrun. I don't want to create a list with all the Jans, then all the Febs, then all the March etc. I want the first 31 days of Jan, then the first 28 of Feb, then first 31 of March etc. in a single list.

Comment: @DJ-AFC Please check my update.  The `list` was created as a temporary option to pull the data all at once.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with the list now though to create the single column I need.

Comment: @DJ-AFC The last step `unlist` gives a single vector which you can create a data.frame by `data.frame(v1 = unlist(.....`)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but this still doesn't do what I need. I'm going to look for a new way to do this I think.

Comment: @DJ-AFC Based on your description, I think this is what I understand.  You have 70 repeated 31 times followed by 66 28 times,....until the DEC, then start again with JAN 2nd set of data.

Comment: That's correct @akrun. By what I unlist each month it is simply all the repeated values for Jan, then all repeated for Feb etc.

Comment: @DJ-AFC In that case it is more simple `unlist(lapply(mget(toupper(month.abb)), '[', 2))` which I mentioned earlier.  I guess there is some confusion from your end in showing what you really wanted

Comment: I finally got it working using your updates @akrun. A few of my files were slightly differently inputted to my example so had to modify certain bits, but it now works well. Thank you very much for all your help - I'm enormously grateful!

Comment: @DJ-AFC Thank you for the update.  I guess the the difference n the files were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = " Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

       1   70  64 58  66  61  59  53  56  69  77  74  72 

       2   70  64 58  66  61  59  53  56  69  77  74  72

       3   71  57 49  62  66  58  55  44  73  87  69  64

       4   71  57 49  62  66  58  55  44  73  87  69  64")



row_pairs <- lapply(seq(1, nrow(df), by=2), function(x) df[x:(x+1), ])
vec_of_pairs <- do.call(c, lapply(row_pairs, unlist))
unname(vec_of_pairs)

[1] 70 70 64 64 58 58 66 66 61 61 59 59 53 53 56 56 69 69 77 77 74 74 72 72 71 71
[27] 57 57 49 49 62 62 66 66 58 58 55 55 44 44 73 73 87 87 69 69 64 64
```